# Lucene index - Export/Query 'indexed' text field values that are not 'stored'

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

I have a Lucene index and the document text is 'indexed' but not 'stored'.

I am using Luke v7.6.0 and it's great for 'visualising' the index.

Obviously because my document text is indexed but not stored I cannot copy or query the 'stored' value (there isn't one), but can I somehow extract the indexed text values to the clipboard or text file to allow me to analyse exactly what is indexed from my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the available thing to you - is to check Lucene [index files](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene70/package-summary.html#package.description) manually.

I suspect that the most important ones are the Term Dictionary files (*.tim)

I’ve indexed document with no stored values and terms - `test@test.com` in field email (*TextField* with *Standard* analyzer) and `John` in field name (*StringField*)

After this one, I opened tim file with hex editor and was able to see something like this:

[image: TIM file]

You could clearly see the values of `test, test, com` which were tokenized by Standard one, also you could see John still stays the same, since I used *StringField*. In my other examples, I was able to see the work of lowercasing as well.

Just a reminder, if you would like to repeat it - by default for small indices Lucene will put everything into compound file, which I don’t prefer for this specific debug. You could disable this by [setUseCompoundFile(false)](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_6_0/core/index.html?org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriterConfig.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have taken a look at my indexes with a hex editor as you suggested and can see the values.  I will play around with the various tokenizers now to see what effect it has on the indexed values. You were a great help!  :-)